# Common XSD for two XML

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have two XML. that contain some common elements and same unique element on the bases of msgtype tag value. I need to create a common XSD for both.
I used choice for unique tags but not working.

### Example:

--XML AAA--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sf:sf700 xmlns:sf="http://www.test.com/schema/sf100">
    <sf:sftMessage>
        <sf:msgType>AAA</sf:msgType>
        <sf:commonElement1>commonElement1</sf:commonElement1>
        <sf:commonElement2>commonElement2</sf:commonElement2>
        <sf:TypeAAA1>AAA7011</sf:TypeAAA1>
        <sf:TypeAAA2>AAA7012</sf:TypeAAA2>
    </sf:sftMessage>
</sf:sf700>
```

--XML BBB--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sf:sf710 xmlns:sf="http://www.test.com/schema/sf100">
    <sf:sftMessage>
        <sf:msgType>BBB</sf:msgType>
        <sf:commonElement1>commonElement1</sf:commonElement1>
        <sf:commonElement2>commonElement2</sf:commonElement2>
        <sf:TypeBBB1>BBB7011</sf:TypeBBB1>
        <sf:TypeBBB2>BBB7012</sf:TypeBBB2>
    </sf:sftMessage>
</sf:sf710>
```

--XSD--

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/schema/sf100" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="sf700">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="sftMessage">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="msgType"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="commonElement1"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="commonElement2"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="TypeAAA1"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="TypeAAA2"/>
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

There Common Element `commonElement1,commonElement2` are same for `msgType AAA and BBB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the structure, but the validation will not be dependent on the msgType value. This can't be accomplished in XSD 1.0, but could be done using XSD 1.1

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2017 Developer Bundle Edition (Trial) 15.0.0.7015 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/schema/sf100" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="sf700">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="sftMessage">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="msgType" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="commonElement1" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="commonElement2" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:choice>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="TypeAAA1" type="xs:string" />
                                    <xs:element name="TypeAAA2" type="xs:string" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="TypeBBB1" type="xs:string" />
                                    <xs:element name="TypeBBB2" type="xs:string" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If you are able to change your XML so it looked more like this, you could accomplish what you want with an XSD 1.0 schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML 2017 Developer Bundle Edition (Trial) 15.0.0.7015 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<sf700 xmlns="http://www.test.com/schema/sf100" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/schema/sf100 XSDFile2.xsd">
    <sftMessage xsi:type="msgTypeAAA" >
        <commonElement1></commonElement1>
        <commonElement2></commonElement2>
        <TypeAAA1></TypeAAA1>
        <TypeAAA2></TypeAAA2>
    </sftMessage>
</sf700>
```

Then the following schema would validate it correctly

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2017 Developer Bundle Edition (Trial) 15.0.0.7015 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/schema/sf100" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="sf700">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="sftMessage" xmlns:q1="http://www.test.com/schema/sf100" type="q1:sftMessageType" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType abstract="true" name="sftMessageType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="commonElement1" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="commonElement2" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="msgTypeAAA">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension xmlns:q2="http://www.test.com/schema/sf100" base="q2:sftMessageType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="TypeAAA1" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="TypeAAA2" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="msgTypeBBB">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension xmlns:q2="http://www.test.com/schema/sf100" base="q2:sftMessageType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="TypeBBB1" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="TypeBBB2" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sprotty.. But when i validate xml this gives 3 exceptions. 1:)  Cannot resolve 'msgTypeAAA' to a type definition for element 'swif:sftMessage'.  2:) The type definition cannot be abstract for element swif:sftMessage. 3:) Invalid content was found starting with element 'swif:TypeAAA1'. No child element is expected at this point.

Comment: Any suggestion xsd is new for me.

Comment: I've edited the post and provided a full example of the XML that schema would validate against.